# Why are there extra arguments in my wcf web service reference?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to convert an ASP.Net web service to WCF application. The client is on the .Net Compact Framework which does not support WCF so I need to make sure the WCF keeps supporting ASP style webservices. When I add the web service reference in Visual Studio the generated proxy class' methods have extra arguments.

For example if a method is defined as:

```
public void GetEmpInfo(int empNo)
```

That method will appear in the proxy class as:

```
public void GetEmpInfo(int empNo, bool empNoSpecified)
```

What causes this, and how do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/eugeneos/archive/2007/02/05/solving-the-disappearing-data-issue-when-using-add-web-reference-or-wsdl-exe-with-wcf-services.aspx) ...

> Where did these extra boolean
>   “specified” members come from and what
>   do they do? The answer is the schema
>   that the WCF data contract serializer
>   generates by default. Because of the
>   way its versioning model works, the
>   serializer generates all data members
>   as optional elements. The older web
>   services stack, ASP.NET Web Services
>   (“ASMX”), uses a different serializer,
>   the XmlSerializer, which maintains
>   full schema and XML fidelity. The
>   XmlSerializer maps all optional
>   elements to two members: one
>   represents the data itself, and one
>   specifies whether or not the data is
>   actually present – this is the
>   “xxxSpecified” member. These
>   xxxSpecified members must be set to
>   true to enable the serialization of
>   the corresponding “actual data”
>   members.

Comment: FYI, these extra methods are also involved when consuming SOAP 1.2 WSDLs served by Spring-WS in .NET 3.5 .

Comment: @GlennBarnett that was my case. They had to change the WSDL information of the element from xsd:int to xsd:integer.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Compact Framework does support a subset of WCF.  You can review this support on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397803.aspx).  Take a look, it may support enough for you to remove your legacy Web Services support.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for types with a default value of not null. In these cases, it's impossible for the web service to know whether a parameter was set to the default value or simply not set at all.

You can get rid of the extra specification parameter by decorating your operation with the `[XmlSerializerFormat]` attribute like:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    string GetEmpInfo(int? empNo);
```

This attribute can also be added at the Class level, and this would make sense in most cases.

I understand you can handle this situation using nullable types (`int?`), but I was unable to fix it using this.