# Why does WCF function returning boolean consumed by vb2008 client give indexoutofrangeexception?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio-2008

I have a WCF service written in vs2010 that is referenced and consumed by a client that needed to be written in vs2008 because of a vendor SDK specification issue (the client is for a barcode scanner and their SDK only works with vs2008).

The 2010 WCF function returns a boolean.

The client, because it is written in 2008, calls the method in the following way:
`methodName([complex_serializable_contract_type],
            [byref return_area as boolean], 
            [byref return_area_specified as boolean])`

When my client application calls this method I am receiving an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

When the return type boolean is changed to integer the same exception is thrown.

When the return type is removed the method works fine (except that my client doesn't get a confirmation).

The service has other functions where the return type is a complex type (array of contracted types) and works fine.

I have heard of wcf not being able to handle certain types that are not serializable, but this is the first time i've run into the issue where primitive types are causing the issue, particularly since I am calling the method with the "specified" argument to handle the .net 1.1 deal with primitives not allowed to be null or whatever that issue was.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the reference to 1.1 - VS 2008 was framework 3.0/3.5 (CLR 2.0).  But yes, there shouldn't be a problem serializing primitive types.

Comment: What I was referencing with 1.1 is the need to provide the (primitivetype)specified arguments.   [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997545/why-are-there-extra-arguments-in-my-wcf-web-service-reference)